# sorted out // How do I remove a class from a button with jquery and add another one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-select

I have a bootstrap-select select element in my project with the following code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
                       

<!-- BOOTSTRAP CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"        integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- BOOTSTRAP JS-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select class="my-2 form-control selectpicker" name="part" data-live-search="true" required>
   <option value="Select Part text-muted border">Select customer</option>
   <option value="">Option 1</option>
</select>
```

In the browser, this code adds a button with a "bg-light" class, as you can see in the image below:
[image]

I would like to remove the "bg-light" class and add the "text-muted" and "border" classes with jquery or JavaScript, how would the code look like? In general, I know I should use ".removeClass("bg-light")" and ".addClass("text-muted border")" to do this, but I can't select that particular button to add those functions

Comment: Please mention the library in use in the future. If you're referring to this library https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#styling you can set the colour class based on the doc. or try manipulate the class by selecting the element next to your original select element like this `$( ".selectpicker" ).next().removeClass("bg-light")`. Note you can only select that button element after it is created by the library.

Comment: Thank you, this comment really was helpful and solved my problem